# C++ class error message: no matching function for call

Tags: c++

My program is supposed to calculate the surface area and volume of a box.  I am to have the following functions: setHeight, setWidth, setLength, getVolume, getSurfaceArea.

**When I compile my program I get the following error message:**

```
boxMain.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
boxMain.cpp:21: error: no matching function for call to 'Box::getVolume(double&, double&, double&)’
Box.hpp:20: note: candidates are: double Box::getVolume()
boxMain.cpp:23: error: no matching function for call to ‘Box::getSurfaceArea(double&, double&, double&)’
Box.hpp:21: note: candidates are: double Box::getSurfaceArea()
```

Based on my searches on this site, most answers seem to suggest that the default constructor doesn't exit or isn't working.  I don't know if that is my issue as well, but I wrote the code for my default constructor according to textbook, so I have trouble figuring out what I did wrong.

The missing lines in my code below are just the descriptions and comments that I removed.

**Any help would be appreciated!  Thank you all so much in advance.**

Here is my .hpp file:

```
 #include <iostream>
 #ifndef Box_HPP
 #define BOX_HPP

 class Box {

 private:
    double h, w, l;
    double height, width, length;

 public:
    void setHeight(double h);
    void setWidth(double w);
    void setLength(double l);
    double getVolume();
    double getSurfaceArea();
    Box();
 };
```

Here is my function .cpp file:

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <iomanip>
 #include "Box.hpp"

 double height;
 double width;
 double length;

 Box::Box() {
    height = 1.0;
    width = 1.0;
    length = 1.0;
 }

 void setHeight(double h) {
    if(h < 0) {
       std::cout << "Error. Height must be positive."
                 << std::endl;
    }
    else {
    height = h;
    }
 }

 void setWidth(double w) {
    if(w < 0) {
       std:: cout << "Error. Width must be positive."
                  << std::endl;
    }
    else {
    width = w;
    }
 }

 void setLength(double l) {
    if(l < 0) {
       std::cout << "Error.  Length must be positive."
                 << std::endl;
    }
    else {
    length = l;
    }
 }

 double getVolume() {
    return (height * width * length);
 }

 double getSurfaceArea() {
    return (2.0 * length * height + 2.0 * width * height);
 }
```

Here is my main .cpp file:

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <fstream>
 #include "Box.hpp"

 int main() {
     Box box1;
     double h, w, l;

     std::cout << "Enter height" << std::endl;
     std::cin >> h;
     std::cout << "Enter width" << std::endl;
     std::cin >> w;
     std::cout << "Enter length" << std::endl;
     std::cin >> l;

     void setHeight(double h);
     void setWidth (double w);
     void setLength (double l);

     std::cout << "volume: "
          << box1.getVolume(h, w, l) << std::endl;
     std::cout << "surface: "
          << box1.getSurfaceArea(h, w, l) << std::endl;

     return 0;
 }
```

Comment: On a side note, your `getSurfaceArea` function seems wrong to me. With `return (2.0 * length * height + 2.0 * width * height);` you are only considering the front, back, left, and right faces, but you should also have the top and bottom one. So I think it should be `return (2.0 * length * height + 2.0 * width * height + 2.0 * length * width);`.

Comment: Also, more on topic: you said that "Based on my searches on this site, most answers seem to suggest that the default constructor doesn't exit or isn't working." The problem is probably the same, but it is important for you to notice that in this case the constructors are innocent. The compiler isn't complaining about them. If it were, it would say `no matching function for call to 'Box::Box()'`. Remember, a constructor has the same name as the class. Here it is clearly indicating another function, so that is where you have to look for errors.

Comment: Your function definitions need to be scoped to the class (Box::setHeight, Box::setWidth, etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one major error in your header file that has nothing to do with your class's declaration, but has to do with the header during the pre-compilation stage. Your header guard is not correct as you have first have your `#include <iostream>` before the guard; this should be after the guard. Second your `#ifndef CLASS_NAME` does not match your `#define CLASS_NAME` and you are missing the matching `#endif` at the bottom of your header file. I will remove the `#include <iostream>` since it is not needed. The reason I am doing this is because if a user enters a value that is less than or equal to zero it will be set to a default value of 1. So there is no need to print out any error messages for this class.

Your class is close to what you need. There are a few things that would help to improve your class and maybe this will help.

**Box.h**

```
#ifndef BOX_H
#define BOX_H

class Box {
private:
    double m_width;
    double m_length;
    double m_height;

    double m_volume;
    double m_surfaceArea;

public:
    Box(); // Default Constructor
    Box( double width, double length, double height );
    // virtual ~Box(); // Default Okay

    void setWidth( double width );
    void setLength( double length );
    void setHeight( double height );

    double getWidth() const; 
    double getLegnth() const;
    double getHeight() const;

    double getVolume() const;
    double getSurfaceArea() const;

private:
    // If You Need Either The Copy Constructor Or The Assignment Operator
    // Remove Them From The Private Section Into The Public Section 
    // Where You May Need To Implement Them Where The Default May Not Be Appropriate
    Box( const Box& c ); // Not Implemented 
    Box& operator=( const Box& c ); // Not Implemented

    void calculateVolume();
    void calculateSurfaceArea();

}; // Box

#endif // BOX_H
```

**Box.cpp**

```
#include "Box.h"

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Box() - Default Box Will Have a 1 x 1 x 1 Dimension
Box::Box() :
m_width( 1.0 ),
m_length( 1.0 ),
m_height( 1.0 ),
m_volume( 0.0 ),
m_surfaceArea( 0.0 ) {
    calculateVolume();
    calculateSuraceArea();
} // Box

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Box() - User Defined Constructor
Box::Box( double width, double length, double height ) :
m_volume( 0.0 ),
m_surfaceArea( 0.0 ) {

    if ( width <= 0 ) {
        m_width = 1.0;
    } else {
        m_width = width;
    }

    if ( length <= 0 ) {
        m_length = 1.0;
    } else {
        m_length = length;
    }

    if ( height <= 0 ) {
        m_height = 1.0;
    } else {
        m_height = height;
    }

    calculateVolume();
    calculateSurfaceArea();

} // Box

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------
// setWidth()
void Box::setWidth( double width ) {
    // First Check To See If Value Passed In Is Same Member Value
    if ( width == m_width ) {
        // Nothing To Do
        return;
    } else if ( width <= 0 ) {
        m_width = 1.0
    } else {
        m_width = width;
    }

    calculateVolume();
    calculateSurfaceArea();

} // setWidth

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------
// setLength()
void Box::setLength( double length ) {
    // First Check To See If Value Passed In Is Same Member Value
    if ( length == m_length ) {
        // Nothing To Do
        return;
    } else if ( length <= 0 ) {
        m_length = 1.0
    } else {
        m_length = length;
    }

    calculateVolume();
    calculateSurfaceArea();

} // setLength

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------
// setHeight()
void Box::setHeight( double height ) {
    // First Check To See If Value Passed In Is Same Member Value
    if ( height == m_height ) {
        // Nothing To Do
        return;
    } else if ( height <= 0 ) {
        m_height = 1.0
    } else {
        m_height = height;
    }

    calculateVolume();
    calculateSurfaceArea();

} // setHeight

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------
// getWidth()
double Box::getWidth() const {
    return m_width;
} // getWidth

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------
// getLength()
double Box::getLength() const {
    return m_length;
} // getLength

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------
// getHeight()
double Box::getHeight() const {
    return m_height;
} // getHeight;

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------
// getVolume()
double Box::getVolume() const {
    return m_volume;
} // getVolume

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------
// getSurfaceArea()
double Box::getSurfaceArea() const {
    return m_surfaceArea;
} // getSurfaceArea

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------
// calculateVolume()
void Box::calculateVolume() {
    m_volume = m_width * m_length * m_height;
} // calculateVolume

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------
// calculateSurfaceArea()
void Box::calculateSurfaceArea {
    m_dSurfaceArea = (m_width  * m_length * 2) + 
                     (m_width  * m_height * 2) +
                     (m_length * m_height * 2);
} // calculateSurfaceArea
```

With the design of this class the calculations for both the volume and surface area are private to this class only for all they do is an internal calculation that get saves into the classes member variable where there are public access methods available to retrieve them. Also each of the 3 dimensional setters does the same check as both constructors for values that are less than and equal to 0 and if so will default them to 1.

If the value that is passed into any of the setter functions is the same that is already stored the function will do nothing and just return. If the value is greater than 0 and is not equal to what is already saved, it will overwrite the member variable and call both of the private calculate methods to update the volume and surface area.

Now if you want to improve this for better performance then you can declare both calculate methods as inline, move them out of the cpp file and either add them into the header file after your class declaration and before the `#endif` or you can add an `#include "Box.inl" and just create another header file type with the same name as the class except with the inl extension and cut and paste these two functions in there.

Comment: Nice extension to the other answers, although I'm not a fan of [Hungarian notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation) :P.  I feel that encoding type information in a variable name is a bit awkward and makes it just a little harder come time to refactor types.  I upvoted you for the efforts.

Comment: @MatthewSanders Especially when using `auto` in modern C++. Imagine something like `auto rgfpUgly = f();` It kind of defeats the purpose.

Comment: Thank you!  Sorry, my knowledge of c++ is still very basic, but is there a reason you added "const" behind all of the double get_ functions?

Comment: I don't use it everywhere; but when I am creating basic simple class types as this; I do use them for my member variables so that when I see the variable name I can quickly tell its type. I don't go crazy with them as in vsoftco used as a demonstration. usually most my variables have a 1 to two character prefix and usually no more.

Comment: @Jamie_Q Yes there is a reason to have `const` at the end of a function declaration. You will only use this when a function becomes a method of a class. What this will do is it will prevent that function from modifying any of the class's member variables. You will usually see this at the end of a function declaration either on getters, Boolean checks that don't modify anything, or printing methods. Anything that accepts a value that is expected to change the internal values of the class object you do not want to use `const` at the end of the function declaration and its definition.

Comment: @Jamie_Q To keep it simple all of these functions that only returns a value from its return section and not by parameter reference is not used to change those values so using the `const` will cause the compiler to ensure that they won't change the class internally. Now there is a way to use this `const` method and still change a classes internal value but that is of a different scope and topic but that deals with the keyword `mutable` (I'm not a 100% sure on this part but maybe even the keyword `volatile`).

Comment: As I stated earlier in my answer there is a big cause for concern for it would cause plenty of compiler errors.  These errors are in the header file that deals with the `#ifndef CLASS_NAME_H` `#define CLASS_NAME_H` `#endif` header guard. This would also be a major problem concerning the users question. Once this is fixed to where the code can be compile correctly is when it becomes the appropriate time of making sure each function or method is implemented correctly! It would be hard to debug the source code for errors if the header files are throwing errors on the pre-compile stage.

Comment: @MatthewSanders I have updated this class based on your response!

Comment: Looks Great @FrancisCugler.  I think the whole variable type notation thing was a concept of OCD practices that predated modern IDEs.  IMHO it always made code more intimidating to read and just added one more uncaught syntax issue as the compiler doesn't enforce it if you changed the type.  Some people still use it, but most engineers I have engaged with over the years prefer to avoid it as well.

Comment: @MatthewSanders I completely understand; as for some of my classes that have various variable types contained; I still may prefix some of them such as f or d to distinguish which is a float and which is a double, same with i and u for the different between an int and an unsigned. Sometimes I may put an e before a variable name to state that it is an enum. Many times with Booleans I don't usually use a b I'll just name the variable hasChanged isThis etc. When working with standard containers such as vectors, lists, maps I'll use a single v, m or l. This is usually for my own reference.

Comment: Sorry for the followup, but when I run the code, no matter what numbers I enter for height, width and volume, my volume and surface area come out as 0.  Am I doing something wrong in my main function or do I need to pass values by reference in these codes?

Comment: @Jamie_Q If you are using my example you shouldn't need to. If you construct a Box Object  `Box box( 3.2, 4.5, 6.7 );`  You should then be able to use this in your main provided you have `#include <iostream>` before your main function; `std::cout << "Volume of Box: " << box.getVolume() << std::endl;` & `std::cout << "Surface Area of Box: " << box.getSurfaceArea() << std::endl;` you could also declare two double variables and set them equal to the function call. Make sure you have `#include "Box.h"` as well!

Comment: @Jamie_Q I won't be able to do it right this minute for I have to run to the store; but when I get back I could update this Answer with a  working main.cpp file.

Comment: @FrancisCugler My main .cpp file finally works.  Thank you so much for all your help!

Answer (score 6):

`Box::getVolume` is declared as taking no parameters, but in line 21 you call it with 3 arguments:

```
box1.getVolume(h, w, l)
```

Use simply `box1.getVolume()` instead. Similarly for `Box::getSurface()`.

Also, use `Box::` in front of *all* member function definitions, like `void Box::setHeight(double h) {...}`, otherwise you end up defining free standing functions and you'll get linker errors since the member functions end up not defined.

Comment: Thanks for the response!  When I run it without arguments, I get the following error message instead: boxMain.cpp:(.text+0xa3): undefined reference to 'Box::getVolume()' and boxMain.cpp:(.text+0xdd): undefined reference to 'Box::getSurfaceArea()' as well as collect2: ld returned 1 exit status.

Comment: Make sure you use `Box::` in front of all member function definitions, otherwise you get linker errors.

Answer (score 2):

vsoftco's answer is mostly correct so I have up voted him, although I feel it would be good to add some more information to the answer to help explain it a bit better as well as help clean up several other issues you have here.

The error you had clearly explains the problem if you look at it.  It mentions boxMain.cpp in the function `int main()` as having the problem.  It further gives you the line number and mentions that there is "no matching function" for the "call" and in both instances notes the call as well as the possible candidates, which in this case is the methods without parameters.

with that aside here are some other tips that may help you avoid further frustration:

1. Prefer forward declarations instead of includes in your header files.  In your case you don't need `#include <iostream>` at all in your box.hpp.  The reason is that anything in your header is effectively leaked into any files that include your header.  This is mainly to help reduce circular dependancies as well as shorten compile times when making changes.  The [Pimpl Idiom](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PimplIdiom) is an example pattern used with this mantra.  I would not recommend using naked pointers, however, instead stick with [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) types such as [smart pointers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer) or plain references.
2. You either didn't paste all of your code or your [include guard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) is wrong.  You need a closing `#endif` in your header.
3. You should use a convention to name your member variables to avoid conflicts and keep your large .cpp files easier to read.  This is a preference more then a rule but it helps.  Something like `_height`, `mHeight`, `_mHeight` rather then `height`.  Lower case camel style variable names are common for locals and parameters.  It also looks like you really don't need the `h,w,l` members at all.
4. You should probably use `assert` for your error handling so as to optimize it out during release builds.  That is of coarse unless you are intending to show the end user the error message.  You may also consider using [std::cerr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/cerr/) instead.
5. The `height`, `width`, `length` variables in your .cpp are also extraneous and do not do what you think.
6. You should use an initialization list in your constructor instead of doing the simple work of assigning to variables in the body.  There are several special situations as well but [this](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/when-do-we-use-initializer-list-in-c/) can get you started.
   ex: `Box::Box() : height(1.0), width(1.0), length(1.0){}`
7. The only method in the cpp you fully qualified with `Box::` is the constructor.  You need to do that with all the methods as well. ex: `double Box::getVolume()`
8. You are also not calling the correct methods in your `main` function (in fact you are not calling methods at all.  You are basically forward declaring them.) you should be using an object to invoke the methods.  This is why you didn't see a complaint in the error log about missing `Box::`

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.  I am still a bit unsure as to what it is about my main function that is causing the error messages.  Am I calling the functions incorrectly?